# linear transformation notations

Tags: notation

I know that *L*$(V_1, V_2)$  denotes a linear transformation from $V_1$ to $V_2$.

What does $L(V)$ denote.

My guess would be that it denotes the homomorphism from $V$ to $V$ but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First $L(V_1,V_2)$ denotes the space of all linear transformations from $V_1$ into $V_2$. So $L(V)$ denotes all the linear transformations from $V$ to $V$.

Comment: I don't know that I would say "so" as if it really follows from the definition of $L(V, W)$  (even though it's probably the only sensible interpretation).

Comment: Actually when $W=V$ then only we write $L(V)$ instead of $L(V,W)$.